# Script to run chown on all folders and setting the owner as the folder name minus the trailing /

Tags: linux, ssh, bash, shell

Some numpty ran `chown -R username`. in the /home folder on our webserver thinking he was in the desired folder. Needless to say the server is throwing a lot of wobbelys.

We have over 200 websites and I don't want to chown them all individually so I'm trying to make a script that will change the owner of all the folders to the folder name, without the trailing /.

This is all I have so far, once I can remove the / it will be fine, but I'd also like to check if the file contains a . in it, and if it doesn't then run the command, otherwise go to the next one.

```
#!/bin/bash
for f in *

do

    test=$f;
    #manipluate the test variable
    chown -R $test $f

done
```

Any help would be great!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming that *all* folders in the /home/ directory represents user names, you can use:

```
for dir in /home/*/; do
    # strip trailing slash
    homedir="${dir%/}"
    # strip all chars up to and including the last slash
    username="${homedir##*/}"

    case $username in
    *.*) continue ;; # skip name with a dot in it
    esac

    chown -R "$username" "$dir"
done
```

I suggest to run a test loop before, checking whether the user name actually matches a home directory.

This AWK command retrieves the home directory for a given user.

```
awk -F: -v user="$username" '{if($1 == user){print $6}}' < /etc/passwd
```

Checking this result against the existing home dir is an exercise for the reader.

Comment: Great that works! Is there anyway to make it so it skips files with a . in their name there are some hidden .* files and some files that are xxx.xxx and so on. Once it does that I can run it and it *should* all work!

Comment: Thanks a lot, saw your updated post and it's done the job! Cheers again

Comment: @Shikoki To prevent hidden dot-names from showing, you can use `shopt -u dotglob` before using globbing. It is not strictly necessary here because `*.*` also matches a single dot though.

Comment: +1 for making proper use of string manipulation. Well done, Sir!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [basename](http://linux.die.net/man/1/basename) command to provide the last component of a path

```
for dir in /home/*
do
    if [ -d "$dir" ]
    then
        username=$(basename "$dir")
        chown -R "$username" "$dir"
    fi
done
```

although I would initially run it as

```
for dir in /home/*
do
    if [ -d "$dir" ]
    then
        username=$(basename "$dir")
        echo "chown -R $username $dir"
    fi
done
```

to make sure it was sane.

Comment: Aye I ran the echo first just to make sure it would do what was expected, I used Lekens code as I never saw yours but thank you anyway!

Comment: @Lekensteyn   Thank you so much for this script! I ran into an issue where I needed EXACTLY what you posted.  You saved me a ton of time.  AAA++++